# Using DefaultTabController in widget tree with variable height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-pageview

In my app I have a PageView and then in that PageView I have some tabbed content (through use of DefaultTabController).  In those tabs, I have some content of variable height.  No matter what I do, whenever I try to use the DefaultTabController, Flutter throws this error:

```
Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TabBarView file:///C:/code/samples/tabbed/lib/main.dart:104:23
```

I have tried:

- Wrapping everything in a ListView with shrinkWrap: true
- Using a Column with a minimum Main Axis Size

No matter what I do the TabBarView always tries to render off into infinity.  How can I use a DefaultTabController to show variable height tabs?

This is my code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: DefaultTabController(
              length: 2,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        text: "Okay",
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: "Go",
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          Text("one"),
                          Text("two"),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.cyan,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `ListView` and wrap `TabBarView` with `Expanded`, and you should be good to go:

```
Expanded(
  child: TabBarView(
    children: [
      Text("one"),
      Text("two"),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Note that now you have a conflict between `TabBarView` and `PageView` swiping gestures (You can only swipe the `PageView` from the `TabBar` since everything below the latter is covered by `TabBarView`)

Comment: Ah yeah, I usually use ScrollPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to overcome that.  I'll try this and get back to you.